# How to "put" maven command line in pom.xml?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

How can I "put" a command line parameter to be executed from pom.xml.
For example I have:

```
mvn clean install -Dmyparameter
```

And I wish It to be executed from pom.xml instead from command line.

Comment: http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Overriding-properties-from-command-line-arguments-td3345432.html

Comment: Do you want to define [properties](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties) in your pom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on which phase you need to use the args. It can be done on plugins by changing  the configuration parameter.

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugin>
        ......
        ......
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <arguments>-Dmaven.test.skip=true -D[other arguments that u need to include]</arguments>
        </configuration>
        ......
        ......
</plugin> </pluginManagement>
```

Same way in the sure fire plugin u can skip test and so on!!

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use maven-exec-plugin:

```
mvn clean install exec:exec -Dexecutable=<absolute path to binary>
```

Also it can be bound to some phase of lifecycle to be executed in the middle of the build (without explicit call by exec:exec) and defined in profile with activation if property exists to run optionally:

```
   <profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>exec</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>executable</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>exec</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <executable>${executable}</executable>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```