# How to set default parameter in maven project?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

To disable cache in my test phase, I need to enter command :

```
mvn test -Dnet.sf.ehcache.disabled=true
```

Is there any way to set this property "net.sf.ehcache.disabled" as default? (Which menas: whenever I specify "mvn test" I want to set this parameter "net.sf.ehcache.disabled" as true automatically)

Comment: Is it an option to configure the surefire plugin like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465351/how-to-put-maven-command-line-in-pom-xml)?

Comment: yes, it will be ok for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to configure the surefire plugin in your pom.xml like that:

```
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <net.sf.ehcache.disabled>true</net.sf.ehcache.disabled>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```